# '[TestNG] Couldn't find the testng.xml in the jar file, running all the classes' error while running test on AWS Device Farm

Tags: maven, testng, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run a test suite on AWS device farm, It is a Maven project, I get the following error on the device farm Parsing result document: [TestNG] Couldn't find the testng.xml in the jar file, running all the classes.
While creating the zip for AWS device farm from Maven I get the following warning:
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details.
I have the latest version of testng and surefire plugin nothing seems to help. any help on this one will be much appreciated.

My pom.xml is as follows:
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.pankanis.cameraplus </groupId>
<artifactId>CameraPlusApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CameraPlusApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <suiteXmlFile>./testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>com.github.genium-framework</groupId>

        <artifactId>Appium-Support</artifactId>

        <version>1.0.5</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>


            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Hi Ronit, I work for the Device Farm team. On Device Farm do you get an error or a warning that it could not find a testng.xml file? It should be a warning and not an error. Let me know.

Comment: Hi NikofTime, you are right it was a warning and not an error, the actual error was/is '[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath: /sikulixlibs/linux/libs64', I could not find a way out so removed my sikuli script. Any help on this will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the testng.xml to the root of the -tests.jar file created.  To do this put it in the src/test/resources directory to take advantage of the super pom configuration.  Alternatively, you can create some testResources tags to reference where the testng.xml is at currently. 
Hope that helps

Just added a pull request here

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/pull/14

[update]

There is now a premium support article about this 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/xml-file-tests-jar-file-device-farm/